# The easiest way to have a multilingual django sites?

Tags: django, multilingual

I have and old django site (0.97-pre-SVN-7457) and I'm about to make some changes and get the site running on the current development code of django.

I have a lot of content that needs to be intact. When I started the site, I made an ugly "hack" to get a dual lingual site, so the result is not pretty:

Here is my model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
title_NO = models.CharField(max_length=500)
teaser_NO = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
body_NO = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
title_EN = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
teaser_EN = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
body_EN = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
...
```

In my templates I have written:

```
<div id="language_NO">
<h1>{{object.title_NO}}</h1>
.....
</div>
<div id="language_EN">
<h1>{{object.title_EN}}</h1>
 .....
</div>
```

And using a simple JavaScript to determine which div to show (Printing the content twice in the template is very ugly, I know!)

So, now that I want to make some changes, what is the best way to go?

I have tried to read the documentation on the subject, but I cant find anything explaining what to do with the urls and templates.

The only current thing I have found is [how to change the language correct](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view)

Comment: The link you provided gives you all the information you need to get going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is this:

in my template:

```
{% load i18n %}{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE "en" %}                    
<h2>{{object.title_EN }}</h2>
{% else %}
<h2>{{object.title_NO }}</h2>
{% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various third-party projects that manage this sort of thing. [Here's one review](http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/).

Answer (score 2):

Google code has a library that provides support for [multilingual content in Django models](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/).

Comment: I hoped someone would point me to a complete example. Still not getting how to set up my templates to use the Norwegian content when the norwegian language is selected, and vice versa for the english content, whith the setup I have in my models.py

Do I do something like this:
{% if language_code.en %}
{{object.title_EN}}
{% else %}
{{object.title_NO}}
...

?

Answer (score 1):

After testing a few applications to translate models, I chose [django-modeltranlation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/).

If you have a look to this comparison http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-translation/ you will also see that it is the most used package, and it doesn't use a second table. Having the translated fields in the same table means that we won't need an extra join.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while and ended up writing a wrapper around the "multiple fields for each language" approach you've described above.

It automatically retrieves the value corresponding to which language you are in (similar to gettext). You can check it out here: https://github.com/zmathew/django-linguo